# Select only groups where all elements of group have same value

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

Using PostgreSQL with pgadmin4, I have an example table like this:

`dogs`

```
+---+-------------------+------------+
|id |breed              | birthPlace |
+---+-------------------+------------+
| 1 | Yorkshire Terrier | Berlin     |
| 2 | Yorkshire Terrier | Berlin     |
| 3 | Husky             | New York   |
| 4 | Yorkshire Terrier | Berlin     |
| 5 | Husky             | Amsterdam  |
+---+-------------------+------------+
```

For an exercise, I want to group my table by the `breed`, make sure there are at least 2 dogs of a breed and then throw out all groups, whose dogs don't all have the same `birthPlace`.

I guess I'll have to set the last statement where the `?` is in the following query, but I'm clueless on how to do so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dogs
GROUP BY dogs.breed
HAVING COUNT(dogs.id) > 1 AND ?
```

Comment: Can you give us sample output formatt. It would be great help

Comment: You have `SELECT *` in your example query, indicating you want to return all columns. Which columns do you actually need to return? Include the total count? Include `birthPlace`? (And what about columns differing across the peer group, if any?) The best solution depends on exact requirements. And always disclose the version of Postgres in use, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not having the same birthplace means that the minimum and maximum values are different.  That should be a pretty big hint on how to solve the problem.

This is easily translated into SQL:

```
Having Count(*) > 1 And min(birthPlace) <> max(birthPlace)
```

Note I changed the `COUNT(dogs.id)` into `COUNT(*)`.  Those should be doing the same thing, and `COUNT(*)` is easier to type and to read.

You might be tempted to use `count(distinct birthplace)`.  I discourage that.  Avoid using `distinct` when you don't need it, because it usually incurs more overhead than the "simpler" aggregation functions.

And finally, both these approaches ignore `NULL` values.  The requirement that all values be non-NULL can be included by including `and count(birthplace) = count(*)`.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me and after some testing turned out to be the fastest. The actual Problem I've been working on is way more complex then my exapmle, so this might not be true for everyone.

Answer (score 4):

I would phrase this as follows:

```
SELECT breed
FROM dogs
GROUP BY breed
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT birthPlace) = 1;
       ^^^ at least two dogs      ^^^ same birthplace
```

The `HAVING` clause asserts that each breed has at least two dogs, and that there is only one distinct birth place for that breed.

Answer (score 2):

Variant with a subquery:

```
SELECT breed
FROM  (
   SELECT breed, birthPlace, count(*)::int AS ct
   FROM   dogs
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1
HAVING count(*) = 1  -- one birth place
AND    sum(ct) > 1;  -- more than one row
```

Should be among the fastest techniques.

The cast to integer (`::int`) is optional. Avoids the escalation to data type `numeric` in the outer `SELECT`. Doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 0):

In `plsql` you have to do something like this (assuming id is not really a column):

```
With que as
(
  SELECT breed, birthplace, count(distinct birthplace) over (partition by breed) counter
  FROM dog
)
SELECT breed, birthplace 
FROM que
WHERE counter = 1
GROUP BY breed, birthplace, counter
HAVING count(breed) > 1
```

Comment: You need `(` not `{`. Plus there is no "PLSQL" in your answer. That's plain SQL

Comment: Plus, the result is quite the opposite of what the question asks.